# Install TA-LIB in Azure jupyter noteboook , facing issues GCC and wheel not created

Tags: python, azure, jupyter

How to install TA-LIB in Azure jupyter noteboook?
Is it possible to install it in Azure notebooks?

I have tried saving the 64-bit binary as a file in Azure library.
But I keep getting the following error:

> ### error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> Failed building wheel for TA-Lib
>     Running setup.py clean for TA-Lib
>   Failed to build TA-Lib